# MVC class not found PHP

Tags: php

i've got my code in MVC pattern. but as i load my page, it give an error
i've tried to add a namespace, but i dont know how it works.

This is my code:

model.php

```
<?php
class Model{

public $string;

public function __construct(){
    $this->string = "My first MVC Project";
}
}
```

view.php

```
<?php
class view(){

private $model;
private $controller;

private function __contstruct($model, $controller){
    $this->controller = $controller;
    $this->model = $model;
}

public function output(){
    return "<p>" . $this->model->string . "</p>";
}
}
```

controller.php

```
<?php

class controller{

private $model;

public function __construct($model){
    $this->model = $model;
}
}
```

and my index.php

```
<?php

$model = new model();
$controller = new controller($model);
$view = new view($model, $controller);
echo $view->output();
```

I hope someone could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to autoload class or load it via include/require

In your index.php write

```
include "model.php";
include "view.php";
include "controller.php";
```

after `<?php tag`

If you don't want to use require/include check out [this link](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/) it is sample autoloader implementation according to PSR-4 standard.

You have also letter mistake in your code

`__contstruct` should be `__construct` also you use wrong definition of class `view` remove brackets from the name

Comment: i get this error by including : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '{' in C:\wamp\www\app\view\view.php on line 4

Comment: I wrote in answer change `class view(){` to `class view{` also according to PSR you should use capital letter for class name.

Answer (score 0):

class view(){ needs to be class view {

Answer (score 0):

Change the names of your classes from view{} to View{} it is the proper way to do it. Also use include / require / require_once for your project. Best way to do it is to use autoloader.

Also you may encounter some problems in your work while learning if you use private instead of public so with that said your work should look like this:

```
- index.php
require_once 'model.php';
require_once 'view.php';
require_once 'controller.php';


$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($model, $controller);
echo $view->output();
?>

- model.php
<?php

    class Model {

        public $string;

        public function __construct(){

            $this->string = "Prvi MVC ";
        }
    }
?>

- view.php
<?php

    class View {

        public $model;
        public $controller;

        public function __construct($model,$controller){
            $this->model = $model;
            $this->controller = $controller;
        }
        public function output(){
            return $this->model->string;
        }
    }   
?>

- controller.php
<?php

    class Controller {

        public $model;

        public function __construct($model){
            $this->model = $model;
        }
    }
```